# Getting information about layer2 connections using scapy

Tags: python, scapy, pcap, wifi

I want to get information about mac addressees "talking" in protocol 802.11 from a pcap file using scapy. I have done something similar that working with tcp connections:

```
    l = self.pcap[int(arg)]
    ipsrc = l.getlayer("IP").src
    ipdst = l.getlayer("IP").dst
    portsrc = l.getlayer("TCP").sport
    portdst = l.getlayer("TCP").dport

    pkt = []
    pkt.append([])
    for i,p in enumerate(self.pcap):
        if p.haslayer('TCP'):
            if p[IP].src == ipsrc and p[IP].dst == ipdst and p[TCP].sport == portsrc and p[TCP].dport == portdst:
                pkt.append([i, p])
            if p[IP].src == ipdst and p[IP].dst == ipsrc and p[TCP].sport == portdst and p[TCP].dport == portsrc:
                pkt.append([i, p])
```

where `arg` is a number that represent packet's ID and `self.pcap` is a pcap file that was opened using the command `rdpcap`.

anyone have any idea how to do the same as the above function but on mac address and 802.11 protocol? thanks.

Comment: Do you want get info about ethernet encapsulation to 802.11 mac header or   802.11 mac header only?

Comment: @Dmitry mac header only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See example for getting mac adresses from 802.11 mac header:

```
from scapy.all import *

pcap = rdpcap('test_wifi.pcap')
for pkt in pcap:
    if pkt.haslayer(Dot11):
        print "Addr1 = %s, Addr2 = %s, Addr3 = %s, Addr4 = %s" %(pkt.addr1, pkt.addr2, pkt.addr3, pkt.addr4)
```

I set my wireless card to monitor mode and save captured packets to 'test_wifi.pcap' file for testing this code.